# Best practive to deploy WinForms app on TerminalServices

Tags: .net, windows, deployment, terminal-services

we develop a couple of WinForms apps, what are used in Terminalservices environment by several users. We deploy the new versions every 3-4 days. The problem is that the users on the TS are always logged it, and using the software, meanind the .exe file is locked, you can not just overwrite it.
We created separate .exe file for everyone: like this: appname_username.exe. And we created a launcer, what checks for a new version, and it copies to the user if needed, than launches it. In this scenario there is no common exe, what is locked, everyone has his/her own executable, what is overwritten in case of need.
For me it looks a bit cumbersome, so if you have any better idea, please let me know.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for StackOverflow. You should maybe try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @PalleDue nope. Code Review is for improving existing and working code only.

Comment: @Heslacher: OK, then I don't know where to go with questions like this.